# How to count tilings on a $2 \times n$ board using the adjacency matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, recreational-mathematics

I am trying to find the number of distinct possible tilings of $2 \times n$ board using only $2 \times 1$ tiles, such that no tiles overlap, go beyond the board boundary and the board is completely tiled with no gaps.

I have approached this problem the classical way by finding a recursive relationship between three consecutive terms leading us to solve the problem using the Fibonacci sequence.

However [this exploration](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/butler/papers/tiling.pdf) shows that it is possible to solve the problem without having to compute any sub-problems by considering the different transitions between columns. On page 4 of this exploration, I am struggling to understand how the matrix $A$ keeps track of where we are allowed to move and why it has been defined as

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and I am unable to understand what the $B_k$ matrix does and why it has been defined as

$$B_k = \begin{bmatrix}b^k_{11} & b^k_{12}\\b^k_{21} & b^k_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$

From these matrices I struggle to understand how we can compute the number of distinct tilings on a $2 \times n$ board.

Could somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the $^k$ on the entries of $B_k$ are *not* exponents. They are indices. But because we also need indices to determine what entry of the matrix it represents, the $k$ index has been pushed up.

With that said, $B_0 = I$ and $B_1 = A$. And in general, the entry $b_{ij}^k$ tells you how many different ways you can tile a gap that is $k$ wide if the left-hand side of the gap is of type $i$ and the right-hand side of the gap is of type $j$.

For instance, the fact that $b_{22}^1 = 0$ tells you that there are *no* tilings of a gap of width 1 such that both ends of the gap are of type $2$. Similarily, $b_{11}^2 = 2$ tells you that a gap of width 2, with both ends being of type 1, may be tiled in two ways.

We see that $B_{k+1} = B_kA$, which gives us $B_k = A^k$. So the entries of $A^n$ tells us how many ways there are to tile a $2\times n$ rectangle. Specifically, since the ends of the rectangle are of type 1 (no domino is allowed to go over the edge), the top left entry of $A^n$ is our answer.

Comment: Ok I understand more now. Although could this method be used to get the same solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624456/how-many-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-no-two-adjacent-1s-and-four-more-0s

Comment: why does $B_1 = A$

Comment: @TomFinet Because by their very definition each entry in those matrices are the same. Besides, $B_{k+1} = B_kA$ along with $B_0 = I$ (a gap of width 0 can be tiled in exactly one way if the right edge and the left edge are the same, and in zero ways otherwise) tells you this as well.